# Truncate in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a way for me to apply truncate across multiple tables at the same time.

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE ',table_schema,'.',TABLE_NAME, ';')
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
 WHERE table_schema in ('mytable1','mytable2','mytable3');
```

More unsuccessfully, it is not truncating the tables.

Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Comment: Your code just generates the code.  You have to actually run the code.

Comment: Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @CODE NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', @XML XML

SET @XML = STUFF((
            SELECT ' ' + data.CODE_DELETE
            FROM (
                SELECT CONCAT ('TRUNCATE TABLE ', table_schema, '.', TABLE_NAME, '') AS CODE_DELETE
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('CITY', 'WORKERS')
                ) [data]
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
SET @CODE = CAST(@XML AS VARCHAR(MAX))

SELECT @CODE

EXECUTE sp_executesql @CODE;
```

the variable `@XML` is to be able to convert the rows into a single value, then we must convert the sql code to `varchar` in order to execute it with
`EXECUTE sp_executesql @CODE;`

you can see the code that will be executed if you do this:

```
SELECT @CODE
```

`city` ​​and `workers` are tables that I have in my database, if you look I change `table_schema` by `TABLE_NAME` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I have the following error in the test done in phpmyadmin. `unrecognized statement type near declare`

Answer (score 0):

Please use transaction to do it if you want to keep it atomic.

```
START TRANSACTION;
// Your truncate statements;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: @LucasL can you post your script and the erorr